# Selecting from a flat table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table with columns like this `SubjectID UserID`. There are many subjectIDs for a single user. I need to do select somehow to get a result set similar to this:

```
UserID1 SubjectID1 SubjectID2 Subject3
UserID2 SubjectID1 SubjectID2 Subject3
UserID3 SubjectID1 SubjectID2 Subject3
```

Comment: @p.campbell, I suspect that he did with his first sentence..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For purposes of discussion, let's define a sample dataset in a table called *SubjectUser* as follows:

```
SELECT NULL AS SubjectId, NULL AS UserID INTO SubjectUser WHERE 1=0
UNION SELECT 'cpsc500', 'maxt3r'
UNION SELECT 'phil507', 'zontar33'
UNION SELECT 'phil507', 'maxt3r'
UNION SELECT 'eng501',  'zontar33'
UNION SELECT 'eng501',  'maxt3r'
UNION SELECT 'bkwv101', 'spaced99'
```

You can then get the desired result using this query:

```
;WITH
  orderedSubjects AS (
    SELECT
      UserId
    , SubjectId
    , 'SubjectId'
      + CAST(
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY SubjectId)
          AS NVARCHAR )
      AS col
    FROM SubjectUser
  )
SELECT *
FROM orderedSubjects
PIVOT (
  MAX(SubjectId)
  FOR col IN (SubjectId1, SubjectId2, SubjectId3)
) AS p
```

Let's look at this query in parts.  The first problem is to assign column names to each user's subjects.  The *orderedSubjects* table serves this purpose, defined by this query:

```
SELECT
  UserId
, SubjectId
, 'SubjectId'
  + CAST(
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY SubjectId)
      AS NVARCHAR )
  AS col
FROM SubjectUser
```

ROW_NUMBER() ... PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY is used to assign a sequence number to each user's subjects.  Arbitrarily, the subjects are ordered alphabetically.  Then, a column name is generated by prefixing each sequence number with the string *SubjectId*.  The result is as follows:

```
UserId     SubjectId   col
maxt3r     cpsc500     SubjectId1
maxt3r     eng501      SubjectId2
maxt3r     phil507     SubjectId3
spaced99   bkwv101     SubjectId1
zontar33   eng501      SubjectId1
zontar33   phil507     SubjectId2
```

We now have the data we need to create the final result.  It is obtained by pivoting *orderedSubjects*:

```
SELECT *
FROM orderedSubjects
PIVOT (
  MAX(SubjectId)
  FOR col IN (SubjectId1, SubjectId2, SubjectId3)
) AS p
```

The application of the *MAX* is necessary only because the *PIVOT* syntax requires the use of an aggregation function.  In the case at hand, there is only one *SubjectID* in each group, so *MAX* could just as easily have been *MIN*.

Also note that the SQL Server *PIVOT* syntax demands that the set of generated pivot columns be fixed in number.  In this case, the query is hard-coded for three subjects.  If the data contains more values than will fit into the allocated number of columns, the excess are discarded.

The final result is as follows:

```
UserId      SubjectId1      SubjectId2      SubjectId3
maxt3r      cpsc500         eng501          phil507
spaced99    bkwv101         NULL            NULL
zontar33    eng501          phil507         NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Which Database are you using ? Microsoft SQL Server (2005 onwards) has PIVOT/UNPIVOT to transpose Rows to columns and vice versa.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: I guess PIVOT is exactly what i need. Could you give me an example query?

Comment: Not near real laptop with sql server on it. Pinal Dave has blogged about it here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/ and also the BOL link I gave above has the example as well

Comment: you may want to consider editing your answer to include the link from you comment.